# How to find by a const pointer key in a map with non-const pointer keys

Tags: c++, stl, const-correctness, const-cast, const-pointer

The following C++ code does not compile because it's passing a non-const pointer to a `find()` function which expects a const pointer.

```cpp
#include <map>

std::map<int*, double> mymap;

double myfind(const int * mykey)
{
    return mymap.find(mykey)->second;
}
```

Is there a way how to make the finding work without changing the type of the map or making variable `mykey` non-const?
After all the function `find()` does not modify the pointed object, it just compares the pointers.

Comment: Use [`const_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast)

Comment: @t.niese Why would you change that? How would it solve the underlying problem?

Comment: After many years, the flaws of the STL interfaces are still there; esp. the typing of associative containers, the lack of binary search...

Comment: Why not changing the key type instead?

Comment: @curiousguy not with C++14's transparent comparators. It's the difference between `std::less<int *>` and `std::less<const int *>`

Comment: @Caleth You pointed me in the right direction by mentioning transparent comparators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution, but it requires C++14 transparent comparators.

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct CompareIntPtrs
{
    using is_transparent = void; // enabling C++14 transparent comparators

    bool operator()(const int * l, const int * r) const
    {
        return l < r;
    }
};

std::map<int*, double, CompareIntPtrs> mymap;

double myfind(const int * key)
{
    return mymap.find(key)->second;
}

int main()
{
    int x {6};
    mymap[&x] = 66; // inserting to the map
    const int * px = &x; // creating a "const int *" variable

    std::cout << myfind(px) << std::endl; // using "const int *" for finding in map with "int*" keys
    std::cout << mymap.find(px)->second << std::endl; // we could even skip using myfind()
}
```

An excellent article about C++14 transparent comparators can be found [here](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/06/09/search-set-another-type-key/).
To be completely honest, by adding the comparator, the type of `mymap` slightly changed which I originally didn't want to, but it's the best solution I could find.

If C++14 is not available, there are at least two evils we can choose from.
The first one is to copy `mymap` to a new `std::map<const int*, double>` in `myfind`, which is horribly unefficient.
The second one is casting away constness by using a `const_cast<int*>(mykey)` which should be [avoided](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es50-dont-cast-away-const) if possible.

Answer (score 3):

A key in a map is semantically immutable, all map operations that allow direct access to keys do that by `const`-qualifying the key type (e.g. [`value_type`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/associative.reqmts#5) is defined as `pair<const Key, T>`).

In case of `int*` key type however you'd get a `const` pointer to non-const `int` (`int*const`), which isn't very nice (it still works, since only the pointer *value* is used as the key, but the semantics of immutability become diluted, which can lead to bugs).

Instead of casting away constness, just change the `map` to `map<const int*, double>`.

Then it will work for `const int*` as well as `int*` keys.

```
#include <map>

std::map<const int*, double> mymap;

double myfind(const int * mykey)
{
    return mymap.find(mykey)->second; // just works
}

double myfind(int * mykey)
{
    return mymap.find(mykey)->second; // also works
}
```

Comment: The **semantic value of the key** cannot be changed in arbitrary ways in an associative container because the container uses the comparison (resp. the hash) to order the objects (resp. store them in an array). But the semantic value of the key here is the pointer value. You can change the `int` without breaking the container.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`const_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) which allows you to change constness (or volatility) of variable.

```cpp
#include <map>

std::map<int*, double> mymap;

double myfind(const int * mykey)
{
    return mymap.find(const_cast<int*>(mykey))->second;
}
```

Comment: Yes but `const_cast` is usually a sign of a bad interface

Comment: I don't recommend any cast, but it is one of possibility ;)

Answer (score -2):

You may have a const-correctness issue. `const int *` [may not be what you think it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const). It is a *pointer to a **constant** integer*. This is not the same as the key type of your map, which is a *pointer to a (non-constant) integer*. And neither are the same as `int * const` which is a *constant pointer to a (non-constant) integer*. The issue isn't whether the key value itself is mutable or immutable, it's whether the things you're storing pointers to are mutable or immutable.

For example, this compiles:

```
std::map<int *, double> mymap;
double myfind(int * const mykey) {
    return mymap.find(mykey)->second;
}
```

As does this:

```
std::map<const int *, double> mymap;
double myfind(const int *mykey) {
    return mymap.find(mykey)->second;
}
double myfind2(const int * const mykey) {
    return mymap.find(mykey)->second;
}
```

Do you see the difference? In your original code, the compiler is quite right to flag an error. If your function takes a `const int *`, then you are in effect promising not to modify the `int` pointed to by the pointer I pass in. But if you use such a pointer as `int *` in the key of a `std::map`, you may be allowing someone to modify that `int`.

In this particular case, we know that `std::map::find()` will not assign to a pointer argument, but the compiler doesn't, which is why `const_cast<>` exists as pointed out in other answers.

Comment: I understand the difference between `const int *` and `int * const`. But you made a good point in the last paragraph. We know that `std::map::find()` will not modify the pointed integer, but the compiler does not know it. And in this question I asked how to let the compiler know it.

Comment: @bedrorom and the answer to that is also in the last paragraph: `const_cast<>`

Comment: Yes, `const_cast<>` is one multiple possibilities. But casting away `const` is [not a good practice](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es50-dont-cast-away-const). A custom comparator (if available) can do the same thing without violating recommendations.

Comment: Completely agree it's not a good practice, but I think unless you change the key type of the `map`, that is in the end what you're doing, regardless of which hoops you jump through to get there. The heart of my answer, which I think is important and valid for readers, is that `const int *` is a semantically different thing from `int *`. To that I don't really have anything to add or contribute; I regret that this did not appeal to the downvoter.